# SQL Server 2008 generate create table and fill data scripts

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 management studio. Is it possible to generate 1 script from a database on localhost and run it on a production database? I'd like both the schema and data to be transfered to the online database.

How do I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the database in sql management studio then click tasks->generate scripts. It will bring up a wizard that will let you generate scripts for re-creating the db schema and data.